# 'Signed file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'' when installing MYSQL8 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, public-key, mysql-8.0

**Intro:**

I am going to install *MySql8* in *Ubuntu 18.04*. I took the following Steps:

*Step 1:* Create a file named `mysql.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

*Step 2:* The following lines were added to `mysql.list`:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic mysql-8.0
```

*Step 3:* Update Repositories using `apt update` command.

**My Problem:**

But I get the following error:

```
root@my:~# apt update 
.....
.....
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                    
Get:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease [5,309 B]                                           
Err:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done        
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Note:**

I try to add `[trusted=yes]` option to `mysql.list`, but again  get the below error:

```
Err:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic Release.gpg
  Signed file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done  
E: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic Release: Signed file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```